# JavaScript - Cannot Update Array Object Properties Inside Nested For Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following nested loops:

```
for(var i = 0; i < availabilities.length; i++){
    if(availabilities[i].round === 1){
        //  Return the indices of all objects which share the same event_team_user_id property
        var indices = helperService.findArrayIndices(availabilities, 'event_team_user_id', availabilities[i].event_team_user_id);
        for(var x = 1; x < indices.length; x++){
            availabilities[x].status = availabilities[i].status;
            console.log(availabilities[x]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(availabiities);
```

The above should find all array objects associated with a particular round (in this case round 1) and then update all other array objects' status property to match the first round's status if those array objects have the same *event_team_user_id* property.

`console.log(availabilities[x]);` nested within the two loops correctly outputs the array object, but `console.log(availabiities);` returns an array object where the changes made in the for loops to the *status* property aren't reflected.

Why are the updated properties in the array objects not being saved?

Comment: Can you add a sample object?

Comment: looks like a typo...

Comment: @tehhowch Yes, `availabiities !== availabilities`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume `availabiities` is a typo from typing out the question since you already mentioned it printed something, it appears your second `for` loop may have some issues.  You aren't using the `indices` returned from your `helperService`.  You should be doing `indices[x]` to access the correct index of `availabilities` and `x` should start at 0.

```js
let availabilities = [
  {
    round: 1,
    event_team_user_id: 1,
    status: 'shouldmatch'
  },
  {
    round: 2,
    event_team_user_id: 2,
    status: 'shouldnotchange'
  },
  {
    round: 3,
    event_team_user_id: 1,
    status: 'shouldchange',
  },
  {
    round: 4,
    event_team_user_id: 3,
    status: 'shouldnotchange',
  },
  {
    round: 5,
    event_team_user_id: 1,
    status: 'shouldchange'
  }
];


for(var i = 0; i < availabilities.length; i++){
    if(availabilities[i].round === 1){
        //  Return the indices of all objects which share the same event_team_user_id property
        var indices = [2, 4];
        for(var x = 0; x < indices.length; x++){
            const curr = indices[x];
            availabilities[curr].status = availabilities[i].status;
        }
    }
}
console.log(availabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got wrong typo

**before**

```
console.log(availabiities);
```

**after**

```
console.log(availabilities);
```

Comment: Don't bother posting an answer for typos, just vote to close.